# can't send POST request to my PHP page with fuel kotlin

Tags: php, kotlin, post

i'm new on stackoverlow so sorry for any possible error
I've recently started kotlin and i'm doing a chat for android
Here's the code that i'm using

```
FuelManager.instance.basePath = "http://mySyte.altervista.org"
    var data=""
    var json="{"
    var i=0
    while(i<postData.count()){
        json+="\""+postData[i]+"\""
        if(i%2==0)
            json+=":"
        else if(i!=postData.count()-1)
            json+=","
        i++
    }
    json+="}"
        Fuel.post("prova.php")
            .jsonBody(json)
            .responseString() { result -> data= result.get() }
```

And here is what i use on php

```
if (isset($_POST['UserName'])) {
$UserName = $_POST['UserName'];
} 
else {
    $UserName = null;
    echo "ciao";
}
if (isset($_POST['Password'])) {
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];
} 
else {
    $Password = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved: i just needed to add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to my AndrodiManidest.xml because since android pie by default you can't send cleartext string to web